# Have Django templates render registration/login form and React rest of the application

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-fullstack

Is it a good approach to have Django built-in templates to handle login/registration views, which on successfull login would redirect to a login required view with html template that has the React application embeded in it? Rest of the communication would be a django-rest-framework and React-query or redux-saga on the frontend. Obviously no request without the user authorized will be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if the only client will be web.

No if maybe later you will have another clients for that api (like andriod app, ios app, or microservices calls) that need authenticate.

Comment: If non-web clients are anticipated, are you saying that it's better to just build all the views (auth-related functions included) as REST endpoints?

Comment: @DJRamones yes, that exactly that i'm saying because you will reuse them and you will have just one way to do it(rest) and not two(web and rest).